# Can't install flask_sqlalchemy ->ImportError: No module named flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have flask installed via virtualenv, and I used `source bin/activate` to use flask. Flask returns fine, but I cannot import sqlalchemy or flask-sqlalchemy (or flask_sqlalchemy) at all.

I used `pip list` and it shows that both installations are there. My Mac is a fresh install, and I have found no resolutions online. I feel like this is a $PATH error, but I am not certain. Any help at all?

```
(project) ➜  project pip list    
click (6.4)
Flask (0.11.dev0)
Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.1)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
pip (8.1.1)
setuptools (20.6.7)
SQLAlchemy (1.0.12)
Werkzeug (0.11.5)
wheel (0.29.0)

(project) ➜  project flask-sqlalchemy
zsh: command not found: flask-sqlalchemy
(project) ➜  project flask_sqlalchemy
zsh: command not found: flask_sqlalchemy
(project) ➜  project sqlalchemy
zsh: command not found: sqlalchemy
```

Comment: check if it exists in your `sys.path`

Comment: it is not there. i do not know why. i used a virtualenv wrapper, i've tried to install with --upgrade, uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to somehow run the python modules right from the command line (zsh in this case).  Does it work if you launch a python interpreter and then use `import sqlalchemy`?

Comment: this was it. I was using a package in Atom that allows you to run code, and when I tested my code within the editor, sqlalchemy couldn't find the module. I typed Flask in the terminal and I got results, so I applied the same logic for sqlalchemy, with no results. 

Using python inside the virtualenv registered. I guess I need to stop running code inside of Atom when using modules to see if they're importing correctly.

Comment: however I still can't use "python <myfile.py" that imports sqlalchemy from flask_sqlalchemy. Confusing I guess, that it works in the intepreter, but not this file.

Comment: I figured out this last part, which is another issue I guess. If I run ./<myfile.py> no modules will import (if I make the file an executable). Only with python <myfile.py> do files import. No idea why that is. hopefully someone else gets value out of this as well.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Are you saying when you run ./foo.py, no modules import, but when you run python foo.py they do import (assuming your file is called foo.py haha)

Comment: exactly what you mean.can't import modules when i run ./foo.py, but works with the python foo.py

Comment: What error does it give? Can you paste the stack trace?